# How to cast named string type to string

Tags: ocaml

I have a named string type:

```
type t = string
```

So I can do this:

```
let (x:t) = "Hello";;
(* val x : t = "Hello" *)
x ^ "Hi";;
(* - : t = "HelloHi" *)
```

My question is how can I get the string `x` back to type *string* in order for me to use it as a string elsewhere?

The main constraint is that I **don't** want to change the type t to use a constructor like this:

```
type t = StringType of string
```

Is what I want to do possible?

Comment: look like that type definition is just a synonym. see this MOOC : https://www.france-universite-numerique-mooc.fr/courses/parisdiderot/56002/session01/courseware/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @PierreG says, your type `t` is just a synonym for `string`. You don't have to do anything to be able to treat values of type `t` as strings.

One reason you might be wondering about it is that the toplevel needs to choose among the available synonymous names for a type. It tries to pick one that seems like the way you've been thinking about the value recently. But all the names (like `t` and `string`) are equally valid.

Comment: The reason I was wondering this is that elsewhere in my project I am instantiating a variable `type n = ... | Atom of string` but when I do `Atom s` I am getting an error `This expression has type Tptp_ast.plain_word but an expression was expected of type string`. Here `Tptp_ast.plain_word` is a synonym for `string`

Comment: You can make types abstract at a module interface. Other than that (possibly not helpful) observation, I think I'd have to see your code to help more.

Comment: http://hastebin.com/munogevabu.vbs here is the code if you are willing to have a quick look :)

Comment: Alas, I have found the problem. The type was marked as private in the `.mli` file. Is there a way to get around this, or do I have to edit the file?

Comment: If you ask for the type to be private in your module interface, then the type is no longer just a synonym for `string`. You can write an identity function that takes the abstract type and returns `string`. When inlined, this should generate no code. But this likely defeats your reason to make the type private.

Comment: Okay I think I'll be ok now. Cheers for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do it, on my toplevel (OCaml 4.01.0) this is perfectly fine:

```
# type t = string;;
type t = string
# let x:t = "Hello";;
val x : t = "Hello"
# String.contains x 'H';;
- : bool = true
```

But I don't get the requirement of aliasing the type, OCaml type inference is quite powerful so explicit type declaration can be usually avoided and let the compiler infer them for you.

For example

```
# type t = string;;
type t = string
# let f x y = compare x y;;
val f : 'a -> 'a -> int = <fun>
# let x : t = "Hello";;
val x : t = "Hello"
# let y : t = "Hello";;
val y : t = "Hello"
# f x y;;
- : int = 0
```

There is no requirement to annotate `f` with any explicit data type.

Comment: agree with Jack, no need to "cast" it to string - as it is a synonym (so same type, just another name). by the way, in 4.02.1 the type "string" is already a synonym ("bytes").